# NLE - Workflow for editing one big video clip containing many sequences

Tags: workflow, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm not sure what would be a good way to edit a big video clip containing many distinct sequences.

Before starting to put the final video together, I'd like to cut the individual sequences, give them a name, and put them in a place from where they will be easily accessible later. It would be great if my timeline could avoid being used as a 'storage' location, since I think it would clutter the view of the actual edit.

What I've done up until now :

1. Imported the video file, and made a meta-clip containing the audio and video clip.
2. Made soft cuts at every sequence break, and given all meta-clips relevant names

One way I can think of to proceed would be to export all the meta-clips as individual videos, and then make a separate blender file to make the final video by importing the intermediate files.

Is there an automated way to do this, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another scene named after the clip then import the long clip. Soft cut it or metastrip the parts as you wish. Then copy paste these elements back to the master edit scene.
You can have as many additional clip scenes as you wish.